# Why were some lightsaber effects in A New Hope different quality?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber

In the below pictures, you can clearly see the difference of quality, when Luke uses Anakin's old lightsaber, its a pale green, almost pure white blade. Its like George Lucas forgot to send this scene to his cgi team and it never got the visual upgrades that Obi-wan's lightsaber did.

Anakin/Luke's Lightsaber was most definitely blue as seen in the 3 prequels and *The Empire Strikes back*, so for it to be that weird pale green or white colour, seems awefully strange that Lucas never upgraded its visuals. Was this ever address by George?

[image: Obi-wan vs Darth Vader]
[image: Anakin/Luke Skywalker's Lightsaber]

Comment: +1 I often wonder this myself. I also notice that the lightsabers seem thinner and more pointy compared to Episodes I-III.

Comment: Are suggestions that there should be *more* changes acceptable here? ;)

Comment: They are mood-sabers. The size and color of the blade reflects the wielder's mood.

Comment: @Xantec [*I see your Schwartz is as big as mine"*](http://movieclips.com/PWVBE-spaceballs-movie-i-see-your-schwartz-is-as-big-as-mine/)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

According to most blogs I read, this was basically special effects fluke. Some claim that his error is corrected in one of the menus on the bonus disc to the OT DVDs.

Remember that original props were all white ([src: Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Lightsaber#Prop_design_and_effects))

---

**UPDATE**: According to [http://www.dvdactive.com/editorial/articles/star-wars-the-changes-part-one.html (archived)](https://web.archive.org/web/20160304051845/http://www.dvdactive.com/editorial/articles/star-wars-the-changes-part-one.html), here is original theatrical release LS:

[image]

... vs Special Edition's crisper blade:

[image]

... vs. "Green" blade on 2004 DVD release:

[image]

... vs. FINALLY fixed Blue colored blade in Blu-Ray release:

[image]

---

**However:** They didn't fix ALL the shots!!!! :(

2004 DVD:

[image]

... vs. Blu-Ray

[image]

---

**Please note that the same linked page also shows differences between Vader's blade in some shots (white vs. red) being fixed**

Comment: interesting, I have the bluray discs and I don't remember seeing any visual upgrades, only the really bad colouring. Will check again tonight. +1 btw!

Comment: Confirmed its that weird pale blue colour to begin with then it reverts to that plain white saber. Still would like to know why he never fixed it properly over how many iterations he has "upgraded" to the original trilogy over the years...

Comment: @Jared - so he could have an excuse to release "Platinum ray extra special uber rare edition"?

Comment: I'm still waiting for the holographic edition :p p.s that link is really great!

Comment: I've also heard an argument that the "white" blade was some sort of "training" setting on the saber that Luke or Obi-Wan turned on for safety's sake. At this point, Luke may have had barely five minutes of practice with the lightsaber!

Answer (score 6):

I always thought it was meant to indicate a mode of the light saber that was specifically for training, perhaps the blade wasn't as strong and wouldn't slice thru the training globe or a person or whatever else someone not used to a deadly weapon might accidentally hit with it. I figured those knobs and switches on the hilt must do something, so a white blade just means the power is turned wayyyy down for safety purposes!

What bothers me worse than the whitish blade in the practice scenes is the film jump from missing frames when Luke ignites his light saber in Bens hut when he first gives the saber to him. Why has Lucas never fixed this? It is easily the most distracting jump in the whole trilogy (worse than Han/Greedos unnatural jumps) and takes me completely out of the film everytime it happens.

Comment: If you have a new question please use the [Ask Question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) feature (found at the top-right of every page).

Answer (score 0):

They didn´t have the same technology we have now. Remember, this is 1977 this was made in. the original lightsabers were literally light running up a pipe powered by a cord running up their sleeve. Look up force saber if you don´t believe me. They have been going back and editing when technology advances so it doesn´t get to where it starts looking cheesy.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "lookup if you don't believe me" part? We don't like answers that tell us to look elsewhere, bring whatever content or information you can *here*.

Comment: i can send the link for the image but that´s the most i can because it won´t let me post the image. here´s the link: <img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQFFNsr2Tfk4R_BXay9Tm4sA5d5yuh6YYFweRDZmisqVhxgWB5Ldw:i.imgur.com/5as5Atu.jpg" alt="Image result for chord on light saber"/>

Comment: so there you go. just use that.