# Where is Obi-Wan's lightsaber?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope, lightsaber, revenge-of-the-sith

In *Episode III* (final battle), we can see Kenobi vs Vader (Anakin) and two white lightsabers. After he defeats Vader, Kenobi takes Vader's lightsaber and (I think) keeps his own.

In *Episode IV*, Ben Kenobi gives a white lightsaber to Luke, telling him that it belonged to his father.

Had Kenobi lost his own lightsaber?

Comment: doesnt he have a lightsaber when he fights vader at the end of 4?

Comment: I think the point he is making with the question is that the lightsaber seen in A New Hope is not the same lightsaber as the one he wielded against Vader in episode III.  The problem is simple:  George Lucas did not care at all about the quality of the writing, acting, or consistency of his new movies in regards to the originals.  Then again, it's also been nearly twenty years(in story), so the old lightsaber may have just worn out.

Comment: i agree its not unreasonable for it to be a different light saber after 20 years, i mean they go through tons of them in episode 1-3 anyway over a like 10 year period lol.

Comment: @Himarm I do not know what saber is it. Is it the same he give to Luke (and used to train Luke on Millenium)? Or luke scaped with another saber?

Comment: @MagnoC - I suspect that you're getting downvoted because a quick search would have answered your question - (*"This question does not show any research effort"*)

Comment: @Richard is not too clear for me. I think it is the same saber and Luke scaped with no one, making one by himself later.

Comment: Obi Wan and Anakin fought at the end of Ep3. Obi Wan took Anakin's sword which he gave to Luke at the start of Ep4. Obi-wan kept his sword (the same one) until his death in Ep4.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unless I've completely misunderstood the question, Obi-Wan still had his lightsaber by the time he fought Darth Vader in the little known cult b-movie *Star Wars: A New Hope* as you can see from this picture below.

[image: Obi-Wan in his traditional brown and tan Jedi robes with his hood up wields his blue lightsaber and stands off against Darth Vader with his red lightsaber; Vader's back is to the camera and we only see his shoulder]

Comment: I've heard good things about that movie, I'll have to check it out one day.

Comment: It's a flash in the pan. Don't bother, nothing will come of it.

Comment: I think it is the same saber and Luke scaped with no one, making one by himself later.

Comment: @MagnoC Here's how it goes: *New Hope*: Luke is given Anakin's lightsaber. *Empire Strikes Back*: Luke loses Anakin's lightsaber at the end of the movie. *Return of the Jedi*: Luke creates his own lightsaber off-screen.

Comment: This isn't the film you're looking for. Nothing to see here. Move along.

Comment: @maguirenumber6: gooood...gooooooood...

Answer (score 6):

No. Obi-Wan Kenobi gives Anakin's lightsaber to Luke.

More specifically, Obi-Wan gives Anakin's [second lightsaber](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Anakin_Skywalker%27s_second_lightsaber) to Luke.

[image: Anakin's second lightsaber]

You can see Anakin holding it in his left hand.

[image: Anakin in his brown and black Jedi robes wields his blue lightsaber and a green one; he holds them above his head into a cross]

You can see in this screenshot that it is the same one that Luke is given.

[image: Obi-Wan sits looking at Luke who has just ignited the blue lightsaber that was given to him and is looking at it in awe]

Obi-Wan *also* had [a blue lightsaber](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Obi-Wan_Kenobi%27s_third_lightsaber) from before the Fall of the Republic.

[image: Obi-Wan and his lightsaber; he wears his Jedi robes wielding his blue lightsaber facing off against an unseen opponent]

This is the one he uses against Vader aboard the Death Star.

As to why Luke's lightsaber looks white, I will direct you to the question [Why were some lightsaber effects in A New Hope different quality?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/11094/5184). In specific, [DVK's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/11099/5184) explains the evolution of the errors in blade colors in the movies.

Comment: Notice the size of the handle changes too.  The original (as in from A New Hope) was much larger than the prop used by Hayden Christiansen in the prequels.

Comment: My, that's a lot of pictures :-)

Comment: @Monty129 I'm not sure how much bigger it is, really. They're holding it completely differently and rotated differently. The protruding edge is visible in Luke's photo, but is behind the blade in Anakin's.

Comment: Look at how Luke can't close his hand all the way around it, and how Anakin's fingers are touching each other though. The slider switch looks much larger in the ANH version as well.

Comment: Luke just has dainty hands.

Comment: Or maybe Hayden Christiansan has big ol banana hands.

Comment: You know what they say about Jedi with big hands. They have big lightsabers.

Comment: Two sabers is just a promo picture. I cannot remember he using two sabers.

Comment: He uses two sabers to kill Dooku, but you are correct in that he normally never wields two.

Comment: In both fights between Anakin and Count Dooku he wields both his own and Obi-Wan's sabers.

Answer (score 2):

He definitely didn't lose his lightsaber.

In G-canon, he uses it to cut off Ponda Baba's arm (first limb cut in the published order [in the long list of limb-cutting in TGFFA](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8555/symbolic-meanings-of-everyone-losing-their-hands/8564#8564)).

In C-canon, in the *"Kenobi"* novel, he used it to fight Sand People right after landing on Tatooine with baby Luke.

Comment: Only movies please.

Comment: @MagnoC - that should have been specified in the question.

Answer (score -2):

lemme splain to you..

Anakin had built a new lightsaber before Ep. 3 and lost it when defeated by Obi-Wan. Obi kept it and his own lightsaber until he gave Luke his father's saber and lost his own when he was struck down by Vader.

Luke kept his father's lightsaber in the Millenium Falcon when he rescued Leia and began training after the destruction of the Death Star. He trained with Yoda for a few days and left for Bespin after using his lightsaber many times on Hoth. Had Hoth not happened, Luke may not've become as good a swordsman as people claim. Experience counts. Once Luke fought Vader on Bespin, he lost his hand and Anakin's lightsaber. (what a shame)

When Luke retreated from Bespin and had his new hand constructed, he went into a cave on Tatooine and constructed a new lightsaber very similar to Obi-Wan's except it had a green blade and a lot more chrome. Luke kept that lightsaber essentially for the rest of his life, even through the foundation and uprising of The New Jedi Order.

Comment: "lemme splain to you" makes you sound like Jar Jar... Was that deliberate? ;)